# Create a loop on a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, while-loop

I want to create a while loop on a batch file.

The file should run repeatedly the following two lines (one is a fortran code and the other a matlab):

```
main.out
matlab -batch "path\matlab_code.m"
```

Now the matlab code saves a file called `boolean.txt` that has a value of 1 if the while loop is to be run again (run again the fortran and that matlab code) or zero to stop it.
I am unsure where to start.

Comment: batch doesn't have a `while` command, but it's one of the few languages where using a `goto` isn't immediately frowned upon, so you can simulate a loop with an `if` and a `goto`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:label
main.out
matlab -batch "path\matlab_code.m"
set /p boolean=<boolean.txt
if %boolean%==1 goto label
```

You can use the [`set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1) command to assign a value to a variable, in this case **boolean**. We are using the `/p` argument to retrieve the value from the user, but by using the `<` we are retrieving the value from the file *boolean.txt*.

At this point, you can verify the value of **boolean** with an `if statement` and loop the code by using the [`goto`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/goto) command, associated with a label at the top of the batch script (I chose *label* in this case).

Hope this wraps up your request, as well as helps you understand batch better, however, please be aware of the fact that you could have found all the answers you needed by searching actively on this forum. So typically questions as general as this one get closed pretty often.